# Regular expression allow numbers and digits validation pattern

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a form input is valid based on a regex pattern using javascript.

The form input should look like this: xxxx-xxx-xxxx allowing for both numbers and letters

Right now it only works with digits as I have it setup which is now being changed to allow letters as well. is there a way to change the regex I have to allow numbers and letters and still format as is?

4 letters or numbers A DASH 3 letters or numbers A DASH 4 letters or numbers

```
validation rule
  medNumber: [
          {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^\d{4}?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/,
            message: "Please enter your #.",
            trigger: ["submit", "change", "blur"]
          }
        ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[A-Za-z0-9]` will match only alphanumeric characters.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}?[-]?[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[-]?[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$/
```

I've also removed the spaces from within your instances of `[- ]` because that will allow matches such as

```
xxxx xxx xxxx
```

In your spec you mention a dash is required, not a space.

Answer (score 2):

The rule `\d` allows only for digits. So you need to change every occurrence of this to `\w`, which allows any alphanumeric character (letters and digits). So you'd get the following:

```regex
/^\w{4}?[- ]?\w{3}[- ]?\w{4}$/
```

For future reference, I'd suggest looking at [regexone.com](https://regexone.com/). It has helped me a ton with learning all the regex rules. You can also use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for easy testing of regex patterns.

Edit:
I was probably a bit too quick on this one. As @David mentioned in the comment, `\w` also includes underscores. If you don't want that, you should look at his answer instead :)

Comment: Just a heads up that `\w` also matches underscores `_`

Comment: @David Ah! I completely forgot about that. Thanks for the heads-up. I edited my answer to reference yours if he'd prefer without underscores :)